# How do I use this async function's callback parm to know when my function finished executing?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, ffmpeg

New to flutter and async programming in general. I want to use this function:

https://pub.dev/documentation/ffmpeg_kit_flutter/latest/ffmpeg_kit/FFmpegKit/executeAsync.html

I don't understand the part that says

> *You must use an FFmpegSessionCompleteCallback if you want to be notified about the result.*

Can someone explain how to use this as if I was a beginner programmer? Is this parameter something I can use to print a simple message to the console, like 'execution finished'?

**What I've tried so far**:

```
String test1() {
    return 'FFMPEG FINISHED';
  }

...later in the code

await FFmpegKit.executeAsync('ffmpeg -i ' + FileDir.path + currentFilename + ' ' + FileDir.path + currentOutputFilename + '.mp3', test1());
```

This gives an error pointing to the end of the `await FFmpegKit...` line: `The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(FFmpegSession)?'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback will be invoked when the operation completes.  However, when you do

```dart
await FFmpegKit.executeAsync(..., test1());
```

you're not passing a callback.  Instead, you're *invoking* your function yourself and passing the result (which fails with a type error).

You need to pass the function itself, not the result of invoking it:

```dart
await FFmpegKit.executeAsync(..., test1);
```

Additionally, your `test1` callback has the wrong signature, and it will not do anything since it just returns a value that won't be used anywhere.  You therefore need to make an additional change:

```dart
void test1(FFmpegSession session) {
  print('FFMPEG FINISHED');
}
```

Comment: Ok most of your answer makes sense except for the last part. Why do I need to add `FFmpegSession session` as a parameter to my `test1` function? Why does it matter if my function has this parameter or not if all I want to do is print something to the console?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat `executeAsync` expects the completion callback to be of type [`FFmpegSessionCompleteCallback`](https://pub.dev/documentation/ffmpeg_kit_flutter/latest/ffmpeg_session_complete_callback/FFmpegSessionCompleteCallback.html), which takes an `FFmpegSession` argument. `executeAsync` will invoke the callback with an `FFmpegSession` argument, whether your callback uses it or not.  Your callback therefore must accept an `FFmpegSession` argument.

Comment: Ohh ok so a callback is of a certain type when it takes in an argument of that type?

Comment: @whatwhatwhat I don't understand what you're asking, but when you call any function, the caller must pass it arguments with the types that the callee expects.  A function passed as an argument (a callback) is just like any other argument.  Functions have types ("signatures") that specify the return type and parameter types.